# Send data from Woocommerce Checkout Page to another path

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

I want to send data from a checkout form to a link (a site).

I suppose that I should change the `action` from the form below, but I don't get the necessary result.

```
<form name="checkout" 
      method="post" 
      class="checkout woocommerce-checkout" 
      action="<?php echo esc_url( wc_get_checkout_url() ); ?>" 
      enctype="multipart/form-data">
```

Who knows how to solve this issue?

Comment: " but i don't get the necessaire result" what exactly is the result you are looking for?

Comment: @jrswgtr, i want to know if changing the `action` is a correct way of solving my problem.

Comment: If we don't know exactly what your problem is, we can't tell you if changing `action` will solve it. You said "I don't get the necessary result". Well, what is the result you are expecting?

Comment: @jrswgtr, i tried to change `action` with  'mypage.php', and after submiting the  data i dind't get the data from form in mypage.php. So, this is why i supposed that adding a link in `action` also won't work. My question is, it is correct to change the `action` in my case?